# Should I remove phrases like "any help is appreciated"?

Tags: discussion

A lot of posts end with phrases such as, "any help is appreciated."

In my opinion, this is superfluous and should be removed for the sake of brevity.

**Is it OK to edit these questions and remove that kind of phrase?**

I've seen similar posts on meta suggesting that salutary phrases at the beginning of posts should be removed, albeit some posters may have hurt feelings from such edits.

Comment: You can remove it as part of a larger effort to improve a post, but please don't go on a mass editing spree to specifically remove this phrase and otherwise leave questions unmodified.